# For a VS Code extension, is it possible to display custom content inside the "Variables" viewlet?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When debugging in VSC, we often use the "Variables" viewlet.

[image]

Here are my requirements. I want to create an extension that communicates with a server and receives responses (presumably JSON). I want to show the responses in a way to allow users to inspect them, and the "Variables" viewlet seems to be a good place.

**My question is: Is it possible to display custom content there?**

Comment: Why not create a new viewlet in the debug group and put your content there

Comment: Any references on how to do that? The reason I want to reuse Variables viewlet is that its usage and meaning are already familiar to users.

Comment: I have done it in this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look.